# Use of unresolved identfiler 'paths'というコンパイルエラー

Tags: swift, realm

OSXでは問題ないのですがiOS用にソフトを作るとえらーになります。

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
extension String : CollectionType {}

class dic: Object {
    dynamic var ID = 0
    dynamic var yomi = ""
    dynamic var kaomoji = ""
    dynamic var date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "ID"
    }
}

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {
    var DBdir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    var realmPath = (paths[0] as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("Test.realm")

・・・

}
```

「paths」がエラーの原因のようです。

```
Use of unresolved identfiler 'paths'
```

OSXとの違いは

```
import Cocoa
```

なんですが、iOSでは「import Cocoa」自体がエラーになります。

解決法を教えていただけると助かります。

よろしくお願いいたします。

追記：
これが答えなのかなぁ？

```
    let defaultPath = Realm.defaultPath
    let defaultParentPath = defaultPath.stringByDeletingLastPathComponent

    if let v0Path = bundlePath("Test.realm") {
        try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(defaultPath)
        try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(v0Path, toPath: defaultPath)
    }
```

Comment: iOSにCocoaは無いので、import Cocoaはimport Foundationとする必要がありますね。pathsが"Use of unresolved identfiler 'paths'"ということはエラーメッセージの通りで、paths変数がそれまでに定義されてないですね。そのコードの前の部分がどうなっているかを追記してください。

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。追記いたしました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず、iOSにCocoaフレームワークは無いので、OS XでいうところのCocoaである`UIKit`か、OS XにもiOSにもある基本的なアプリケーションを作るためのフレームワークである`Foundation`をインポートしましょう。

次の

```
Use of unresolved identfiler 'paths'
```

というエラーメッセージですが、書いてある通りで、`paths`という変数が突然使われていて、それ以前に定義されてないためです。

あと、クラスのインスタンス変数に処理を書くのも制限があるので、Computed Propertyにして、下記のようにすると良いと思います。

```
class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {

    var realmPath: String {
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let path = (paths[0] as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("Test.realm")
        return path
    }
```